# How can I change a css style for 'this' class using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of images that each are tied to a class.

```
var hoverList = this.hoverable.getAllList() //this gets the list.
```

on mouseover of the images, I want a block of text in a different area, but shares a class, to display. I call

```
hoverList.mouseover(this.hoverable.displayTheDeets)
```

and it runs

```
displayTheDeets: function(){
    big=$(".project-details")
    thisClass=$(this).attr("class")
    console.log(thisClass)
    //$(big).find(thisClass).css("display","")
    $(big).find(thisClass).css("display", "block")
    //$(big > thisClass).css("display","block")
}
```

From the console, if I run the literal command

```
$(".project-details").find(".code-fusion")
```

it returns the element I want. And I can change the display with no problem.

I think my problem is with thisClass. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: You should put `var` in front of `big` and `thisClass` as you are implicitly creating globals.

Comment: This will stop working when you have elements that contain multiple css classes, e.g. `class="foo bar"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try,

```
big.find('.' + thisClass).css("display", "block");
```

or simply

```
big.find('.' + thisClass).show();
```

Please note that `.attr('class')` would return the class being used for the particular element, and it wont return the class name in the format of selector.

**Additional Note**: And in sometimes if you have more than one class set with that particular element then it would make the selector as invalid like `$('.class1 class2 class3')`

Answer (score 3):

Try with prefix dot. the attr("class") returns only the name not the prefix dot.

```
$(big).find("."+ thisClass).css("display", "block")
```

or

```
 $(big).find("."+ thisClass).show();
```

Comment: sudharsan, we don't need to wrap the jquery object again into $(), it wont cause any benefits..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(big).find("."+ thisClass).css("display", "block")
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem has already been answered well enough; however, I would suggest that you solve this problem in another way.

You can define the class name separately from the class of your hovering element, e.g.

```
<... class="something" data-linked="theclass">
```

Then:

```
displayTheDeets: function(){
    var className = $(this).data('linked');

    $(".project-details").find('.' + className).show();
}
```